# select sql from table 1 then filter table 2 clolumn with table 1 column condition

Tags: sql

I need to find item from table 1 where group id = 1 (result 1)
then those item where group id = 1 , go to table 2 filter result 1 + select those price id = 200 only
table 1 , item id , group id
table 2, item id, price id

I have tried select inner join but cannot filter. union all return error as column data not same.

```
select item id, group id 
from table 1 
where groupid = '1'
inner join 
   select item id, price id 
   from table 2 
   where price id = '200'
```

Comment: It would be easier if you show us some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: You need to explain a little more what you're trying to do. Something like this I'm guessing is what you're trying to do with the join:
select t1.ItemId, t1.GroupId, t2.PriceId
from table 1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.ItemId = t2.ItemId and t2.PriceId = '200'
where t1.GroupId = '1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
select * from table2 as t2 inner join (select * from table1 where groupid=1) as t1
on t1.itm_id =t2.itm_id where t2.price_id=200
```

Comment: table 1 , item id , group id table 2, item id, price id

Comment: @user2201789 can you pls show the result

Comment: so my solution is wrong?

Comment: @user2201789 so my solution is wrong?

Comment: your solution is correct..bew..thanks

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Is it something like this?

```
SELECT t1.a, 
       t1.b, 
       t1.c, 
       t2.x, 
       t2.y 
FROM   t1 
       inner join t2 
               ON t1.KEY = t2.KEY 
WHERE  t1.grpid = 1 
       AND t2.priceid = 200;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!